C# Create subkey and a string
Having some issues creating a subkey... Not sure what I'm doing wrong by doing it like this:
private const string RegistryKeyPath = @"SOFTWARE\XXXXX";

private void EnsureRegistryKeyExists()
{
    using (var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(RegistryKeyPath, true))
    {
            Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE", true).CreateSubKey("XXXXX");
            //Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(RegistryKeyPath);
    }
}

This should work no?
Thanks in advance!

And... what does it do instead of working?

Nothing... No error message what so ever. But I just removed the IF statement i had... Forgot that was just something I tested.

Either CreateSubKey succeeds and returns the new key, or it throws an exception. So which is it?

Wish I knew then... Because nothing really happens. It's being called from form load. And I see no changes in regsitry... Well I guess it "succeeds" but... idk

You mean the key isn't created? Does CreateSubKey return anything?

The subkey xxxx is not created under local machine and software.

Are you running that as admin? Because you need admin rights to create something in HKLM.

Yea, I just tested current user and it works.. But it should be admin. I changed it in the app.manifest.. And I need to launch visual studio with admin to start debugging in the first place.

Are you compiling for 32 or 64 bit? Or did you check the WOW6432Node subkey?

Your code makes no sense. The first line opens the subkey and then the second line tries to create the subkey that you just opened. Have you single-stepped the code to examine the values returned from your function calls? Also, your last comment leaves me wondering if you solved the problem or not. If you did, then either mark the question as closed, or add an answer and accept it.

I bet you're running a 32-bit WinForms application on 64-bit Windows. In this case, any exception thrown from Form.Load() will be swallowed, so you are not seeing the exception that's thrown from your code. See here for the gory details.
